# Avoid branching from a branch in git

Tags: git

Twice now in git, I've meant to branch from master, but instead branched from my current branch by accident. This means that my pull request from the second branch included all of the commits in the first branch, which haven't been merged yet.

Is there a way I can double check to confirm before branching from a non-master branch?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not supply a second parameter to `git checkout -b`:

```
$ git checkout -b newbranch master
```

The second parameter is where to branch from.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using a Unix-type shell, here's a simple function you could adapt:

```sh
function git() {
    if [ $# -eq 3 -a "$1" = "checkout" -a "$2" = "-b" ] ; then
        curbranch=$(git name-rev --name-only HEAD)
        if [ "$curbranch" != "master" ] ; then
          echo "You're on branch $curbranch."
          echo "Confirm new branch creation? [yn]"
          read a
          if [ "$a" != "y" ] ; then
              echo Aborted.
              return 1
          fi
      fi
    fi
    /usr/bin/git $@
}
```

Will only trigger on `git checkout -b one_other_param`.

Note: this will probably not work as expected if you're in a "detached head" state. The `git name-rev` won't give correct information I believe.

Comment: Nice. Of course, you could additionally modify this so that it only prompted if the current branch != master.

Answer (score 1):

Add `$(__git_ps1)` to your command prompt (`PS1` variable in your shell rc file) and you will always see what is your current branch.

Answer (score 0):

if you run

```
git branch
```

you get something like this:

```
  branch1
  branch2
* master
```

And the star marks which branch on which you are currently located.

Comment: yes, I know - the thing is i just run `git checkout -b` without thinking about it. I'd like an automatic warning to flash when checking out from a branch.

Answer (score 0):

You may write bash script, that you will use instead of git.

On creating new branch it will check is you in master.
If no, it will stops(or ask you to continue), and if yes, it will execute real git

For example, you may name it `gitcheckout`